# Can any planar graph have 4 vertices and 4 regions?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

This actually homework question which my professor has assigned few days ago. Question originally says that:

Prove that any planar graph cannot have 4 vertices and 4 regions?

I have found that $K_4$ has 4 vertices, 4 regions and 6 edges and it is a planar graph.

Do you think that I miss something or the question is mistaken?

Comment: I wonder is the version of $K_4$ you are thinking of the non-planar representation? See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) and then [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) by way of contrast.

Comment: See the second image from top. I'm considering this represenation. http://rip94550.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/nonplanar-graphs-the-euler-characteristic/

Comment: @Ada What was the condition for plane representations? No two edges cross?

Comment: @kyticka in short yes, here you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

Comment: ... so as you can see from the planar graph wikipedia page and from the wordpress source you've linked to, $K_4$ has only three regions (i.e. three areas that are enclosed by edges of the graph).

Comment: Actually I am confused at that point because the book (Grimaldi, Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics) I read considers the region outside as infinite region and takes it into account.

Comment: You have convinced us that the statement in your second paragraph is wrong. Now what is the question, the we convince you as well?

Comment: @Ada - your last comment shows the importance of the definition of 'region' in the question. I think you should clear this up with your professor: he/she may be using a different definition to the one in Grimaldi et al. - or as you suggested originally, there may be a flaw in the question.

Comment: My experience suggests that the infinite region is usually included in the counting of regions (c.f. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) explicitly says "regions bounded by edges, including the outer, infinitely large region"). Of course, the problem given as homework might have implicitly assumed the outer region is not included in the counting... Checking with the professor might be a good idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that a planar graph doesn't really have a notion of "regions" *per se*.  To illustrate, this is $K_4$: $$K_4=(\{1,2,3,4\},\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}).$$  To talk about "regions" (typically called "faces") we need to also have an embedding in the plane.

[image: drawing of $K_4$ ("borrowed" from Wikipedia)]

The above drawing of $K_4$ indeed has $4$ faces.  In graph theory, the unbounded face is always included in the counting of faces, otherwise e.g. Euler's characteristic formula would need to be adjusted.